# MySQL encodes string and adds a question mark

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm having a very strange behaviour here.

I copy a table from a PDF, the table is pasted in Excel spreadsheet. Then the .xls file is saved as .csv. Finally, the .csv is uploaded to MySQL trough Php. Some of the text have a hidden question mark at the beginning. Like this one: `NEE13`. I can't see nothing abnormal, but just to test I did a single insert with phpMyAdmin. MySQL complains saying:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBB\xBFNEE...' for column 'rid' at row 1.
```

The resulting value in the database then is: `?NEE13`

Any help to correct this issue is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: care to show us the exact sql query that's causing the error?

Comment: @BenRowe. Hi. This is the query: INSERT INTO `wattquotes_test`.`tbl_duostuos` (`id`, `rid`, `state_id`, `network_id`, `nuoscharge_id`, `duos`, `tuos`, `nuos`, `year`) VALUES (NULL, 'NEE13', '6', '13', '1', '2', NULL, NULL, '2015');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file begins with 'EF BB BF'. They are called utf8 magic bytes, or BOM (Byte Order Mark).

MySQL can't parse these bytes as correct utf8 symbol and replace they with '?' mark.

Just remove these bytes before insert, or use blob/varbinary field to store your file.

Comment: is there any way to do it programatically through Php?

Comment: Something like: $rid = preg_replace('/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/', '', $rid);

Comment: Thanks. preg_replace does the trick. I just wonder why my text has those magic bytes. I reckon it is because is copied and pasted from a Pdf.